An integral equation that satisfies $f_{xy}=f$
For $(x,y)\in[0,\frac{1}{2}]\times[0,\frac{1}{2}]$, $f(x,y)$ satisfies the integral equation
\begin{equation}
f(x,y)=1+\int_0^{1/2}\int_0^{1/2} fdA+\int_0^x\int_0^{1/2} f(s,t)dtds+\int_0^y\int_0^{1/2} f(s,t)dsdt+\int_0^x\int_0^y f(s,t)dtds.
\end{equation}
The four integrals are all over rectangles: the first as a constant; the second depends on $x$; the third depends on $y$; and the last depends on $x$ and $y$. It is known that $f$ is positive, symmetric, i.e. $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$, and increasing. Differentiating with respect to $x$ and $y$, we see
\begin{equation}
f_{xy}=f.
\end{equation}
I am particularly interested in the value $f(0,0)=1+\int_0^{1/2}\int_0^{1/2}fdA$. Is it possible to solve for $f(x,y)$ or just find $f(0,0)$?
For $f_{xy}=f$, I tried separation of variables and got symmetric solutions $f=e^{ax+y/a}+e^{x/a+ay}$, $a\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, but they don't satisfy the integral equation. Equating the coefficients of the Taylor series also fails to give the constant term in an easy way. Can anyone just give some hints? Thanks.

I'm afraid your system is overconstrained  and thus doesn't admit any solutions apart from the trivial $f = 0$.

@Abezhiko Note the constant term $1$, and so $f=0$ is not a solution.
